# limit sql result per column value

Tags: sql-server, union

I am trying to build up a select statement for a cursor.

My table has vehicle events, for my cursor i am grabbing all ignition on and ignition off events in a determined time period.

I would like to union the first and last event of that time period per vehicle to my select via union, my thought is that the where clause for that should be that the event cannot be ignition on or off so it would not repeat itself. But I don't know how to get an event per vehicle.

What I currently have is the following.

```
SELECT  
    al.ActivityLogID,
    al.[VehicleID],
    al.[DriverID],
    al.[ActivityDateTime],
    al.[EventSubTypeId]
FROM    
    [activitylog] a
WHERE   
    [ActivityDateTime] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime AND
    [EventSubTypeID] = 3 -- ignitionON

UNION

SELECT  
    al.ActivityLogID,
    al.[VehicleID],
    al.[DriverID],
    al.[ActivityDateTime],
    al.[EventSubTypeId]
FROM    
    [activitylog] a
WHERE   
    [ActivityDateTime] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime AND
    [EventSubTypeID] = 4 -- ignitionOFF
ORDER BY 
    [VehicleID], [ActivityDateTime]
```

Comment: why are you using a cursor?

Comment: @MitchWheat i am calculating driven times. i have that implemented already, i am missing to have in my cursor also the first non igntion event and also off

Comment: Why do your tables have an `a` alias, but the column list in the `SELECT` use an `al.` prefix?!?!?!?

Comment: If you're calculating drive times between 2 specific times  (you're asking the question "how many minutes did each car drive today") , this can all be done in a single query.  You would have to calculate the number of minutes (or seconds?) between each IgnitionOn and IgnitionOff event, then add all of them together.   its not clear what you're actually asking?

Comment: General rule - if you need a cursor, you are almost certainly mistaken. If you post your data and cursor query you will almost certainly get an answer that doesn't need the cursor. Of course - there is that 1 in 1000 that does need it, its just rare.

Comment: @TomC i need a cursor, there is no doubt on it. Mainly because the kind of analysis made to that data is a bit complex and i know for sure it can't be done in a single query, i need to go and check into other tables if some info is not there and the process is made in machine states so with cursors i can cycle them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that IgnitionOFF is after IgnitionON datetime

```
SELECT  al.[VehicleID]
      , al.[DriverID]
      , MIN(al.[ActivityDateTime])
      , MAX(al.[ActivityDateTime])
FROM  [activitylog] al
WHERE [ActivityDateTime] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime AND
      [EventSubTypeID] IN (3,4) -- ignitionON/OFF
GROUP BY al.[VehicleID]
       , al.[DriverID]
ORDER BY al.[VehicleID]
       , al.[DriverID]
```

or maybe you need this one:

```
SELECT [VehicleID]
      ,[EventSubTypeID]
      ,[ActivityDateTime]
FROM
(
  SELECT  al.[VehicleID]
        , [EventSubTypeID] 
        , MIN(al.[ActivityDateTime]) AS "ActivityDateTime"
  FROM  [activitylog] al
  WHERE [ActivityDateTime] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime AND
        [EventSubTypeID] = 3 -- ignitionON
  GROUP BY al.[VehicleID], [EventSubTypeID]
  UNION
  SELECT  al.[VehicleID]
        , [EventSubTypeID]
        , MAX(al.[ActivityDateTime]) AS "ActivityDateTime" 
  FROM  [activitylog] al
  WHERE [ActivityDateTime] BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime AND
        [EventSubTypeID] = 4 -- ignitionOFF
  GROUP BY al.[VehicleID], [EventSubTypeID]
)
ORDER BY [VehicleID], [EventSubTypeID]
```

Comment: that just replaces what i already did, it does not add what i am looking for isn't it?

Comment: If you want first and last event, the use MIN() and MAX() functions within the group.

Comment: your query gets close to what i am looking for, but it is not quite there, i modified it by taking out the eventsubtype where clause since i need the first and last event, and i need them in different rows. on the other side i am getting the group by driver too and i just need it per vehicle .